# What should I put if there is no "End Date" for a "Start Date" in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a "`Start Date`" and an "`End Date`" to determine the duration of an event. The events are dynamically called in a database with "`Start Date`" and "`End Date`" having `date` datatypes. What if I want to show the following: (`Start Date`) March 26, 2018 - (`End Date`) "UNTIL FUTHER NOTICE"?

What is the best approach here?

EDIT:  I figured what I wanted to do was to put "VALID UNTIL" if Start Date is NULL and put "UNTIL FUTHER NOTICE" if End Date is NULL and just restrict the save button if both are null. I am very sorry I didn't think this through before asking. After reading Yatin's answer, I realized that using If else statements and basing them with null can easily solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think using a `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?` should do the trick.
If the value is absent, null is an appropriate representation of it.

Let's suppose this is your variable:
`DateTime? endDate`

You can just use `endDate.HasValue` property - which returns a boolean or just check for null before using the `endDate.Value` which will return the date that you need.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem Victor.